# Unable to run bluetooth sample tizen watch app on emulator

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

I found a Bluetooth sample app in Tizen studio and this is developed by using HTML, CSS and js.

When I try to install in emulator by using Tizen studio then it pop up an error which says "**Error in Config File**".

please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: could you please the link to the sample app? thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I reported this problem.
Until it is fixed You can use the following steps as a workaround.

1. Delete **.tproject** file,
2. Clean and build project,
3. In auto generated **.tproject** change platform to **wearable-5.0**.